# SQL: How to select one column and order by another one

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a JS chart and I want to provide  custom color to every label (customer), I  have the following Customers Table

*Table Customers*

```
Customer | ColorLabel | Sales
---------+------------+------
AAAAA    | BLUE       | 100
BBBBB    | RED        | 120
CCCCC    | GREEN      | 80
```

For the chart ordered by sales
First select labels

```
Select Customer from Customers order by Sales
```

for  the values

```
Select Sales from Customers order by Sales
```

for the Color

```
Select ColorLabel FROM Customer order by Sales
```

for the labels and color case, none of them include the sales column in the query, how can I match the three concept to be properly sorted to show the correct label and color?

Comment: Select all of the columns in the same query: `SELECT customer, Dales, colors FROM customer ORDER BY sales;`

Comment: hi, but the js chart requiered three different arrays

Answer (score 3):

Well

```
SELECT Customer, Sales, ColorLabel FROM Customers ORDER BY Sales
```

Although a quick search would have shown you.

Comment: I have to create three different arrays  one for the labels [BBBB,AAAA,CCC] the second one for the Sales [120,100,80] and the third one for the colors [RED,BLUE,GREEN]

Comment: Well, iterate over the result array to build your 3 different arrays, or use array_colum (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to split it directly